# Shell Script - Print directories/files & file numbers

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a shell which can print the directories & files in it. I want to add number (for loop) to files in it, but having issues - can you experts look into it and help me out? Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh

BDIR=$1

rm dir.log

counter(){
        for file in "$1"/*; do
                if [ -d "$file" ]; then
                        echo "$file"
                        counter "$file"
                fi
        done
}

counter "$BDIR" > dir.log

while read -r line; do
        echo  "\n Directory Name => $line"
        echo  " This Directory has following File in it...."
        pfile=`ls -l $line/ | awk 'NR>1{print " ==> " $9;}'`
        cnt=`ls -l $line/ | awk 'NR>1{print $9;}' | wc -l`
        for i in $cnt; do
                echo  "$i.      $pfile"
        done
done < dir.log

### Output

    $ ./dr5.sh /home/test
    
     Directory Name => /home/test/scripts
     This Directory has following File in it....
    3.       ==> d_name.sh  ----------> should have 1
     ==> test1  -------------> should have 2
     ==> test2  -------------> should have 3
    
     Directory Name => /home/test/test
     This Directory has following File in it....
    1.       ==> one
    
     Directory Name => /home/test/test/one
     This Directory has following File in it....
    1.       ==> t.sh
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Also, see [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) re: `for i in $anything`.

Comment: ... Consider running the script as a whole through http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - Updated while loop with following - was simple than anticipated :)

```
    cd $line
    ls -l | awk 'NR>1{print " => " $9}' > cnt.txt
    cat --number cnt.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to count the amount of files in a directory, you can do:

```
find ./ -type f | wc -l
```

This includes the subdirectories. If you want the number of files only in the main directory, you can do:

```
find ./ -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
```

It's far more reliable than parsing `ls` count.

Answer (score 0):

Supporse you have the following directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir2
│   └── file3
├── file1
└── file2
```

```
$ find . -type d | xargs -I % sh -c "echo in file '%' ; ls '%' | nl"
in file .
     1  dir2
     2  file1
     3  file2
in file ./dir2
     1  file3
```

- `find . -type d` outputs every directory and sub-directory under and including `.`.
- `xargs` executes `sh -c "echo in file '<dir>' ; ls '<dir>' | nl"` for every directory `find` provides. Which prints `in file <dir>` and then enumerates its content.